# when i try to click to a post it shows me this error: Couldn't find Post with 'id'=#<Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x6311eb0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

## when i try to go to the post show grabbing the id, i get an error

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end

root 'posts#index'

```
#this is the show view

.show
  %p= @post.content



  = link_to "edit", edit_post_path(@post)
  = link_to "delete", post_path(@post), method: :delete, data: {confirm:        "Are you sure?"}
  = link_to "home", root_path
```

## show controller

```
def show
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    end
```

Comment: You want to reformat the code

Comment: Please post the code for the link on which you are clicking

Comment: What do your models look like?

Comment: this is what i am clicking: %p= link_to post.content, post_path(@posts)

Comment: this is the post model: class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 has_many   :comments
end

Answer (score 0):

can you show the page you are linking from?  It seems as if you are passing in a query result (activerecord relation) instead of an ID as your parameter, leading to this error.  One reason could be if you use a where statement instead of a find statement in your link, ie saying

`link_to 'Show', Post.where(id: 1)`

instead of

`link_to 'Show', Post.find(id: 1)`

but we can't give a specific answer unless we can see the page the link is coming from, and preferably more of the error.